# error generate pdf - PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

This have been bugging me for a few hours. When i try to produce pdf, i got this error:
1) Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\KPAPMS\PHP\lib\pdftable.php on line 540
2) FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

i just use the existing code to generate pdf(fpdf).

this is my code example

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * from vesservice";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

$hdd= "<table width=100%>
<tr><th width=100><strong>Company</strong></th><th><strong>: Kuching Port Authority</strong></th><th></th>
<th>Date / Time: ".$date."</th></tr>
<tr><th width=100><strong>Title</strong></th><th><strong>: Water Supply for SCN</strong></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan=4><hr></th></tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>SCN</strong></th><th>:</th>
<th><strong>Berth Date</strong></th><th>:</th></tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>Debtor Code</strong></th><th>:</th>
<th><strong>Expected Depart Date / Time</strong></th><th>:</th></tr>
<tr>
<th></th><th></th>
<th><strong>Actual Depart Date / Time</strong></th><th>:</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan=4><hr></th></tr>
</table>";

$tables="<table width=100%>
<tr align=center>
<th>Service Reference</th>
<th>Service Code</th>
<th>Water Supply Reference</th>
<th>Water Supply Sequence</th>
<th>Tariff Code</th>
<th>Tariff Description</th>
<th>UOM</th>
<th>Service Date</th>
<th>Requested Time</th>
<th>Volume<br />(Tonne)</th>
<th>Service Date</th>
<th>Started Time</th>
<th>Volume<br />(Tonne)</th>
<th>Service Date</th>
<th>Ended Date</th>
<th>Duration</th></tr>";

while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$tables.= "<tr align=center>
<td>".$rs['serv_opt']."</td>
<td>".$rs['dt_code']."</td>
<td>".$rs['scn']."</td>
<td>".$rs['term_code']."</td>
<td>".$rs['serv_cat']."</td>
<td>".$rs['serv_code']."</td>
<td>".$rs['activ_cnt']."</td>
<td>".$rs['serv_date_req']."</td>
<td>".$rs['serv_shift_req']."</td>
<td>".$rs['serv_qty']."</td>
<td>".$rs['serv_ref']."</td>
<td>".$rs['res_serv_date']."</td>
<td>".$rs['res_serv_time']."</td>
<td>".$rs['new_serv_date']."</td>
<td>".$rs['new_serv_time']."</td>
<td>".$rs['new_serv_qty']."</td>
</tr>";
}
$tables.="</table>";
//echo $hdd.'<br />'.$tables;
$p = new PDFTable('L','mm','a4');//set page orientation P/L
$p->SetFont('Times','',10);
$p->headerTable=$hdd;
$p->AddPage();
$p->htmltable($tables);
//ob_end_clean();
$p->output("Water Supply.pdf",'I'); //D=download
```

When i uncommet the ob_end_clean, it can generate the pdf output, but only print $tables but the header is not printed.
Please help me, which part i did wrong.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on PDF generate using DOMPDF.
http://advancetechtutorial.blogspot.com/2015/09/pdf-generate-in-codeigniter-using-dompdf.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try insert ob_end_clean(); before outputing.
Example

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
//your code for eneration of the pdf
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: yes.. i tried it and it work, but i dont want to put it as my friend also did the same program and works without using ob_end_clean(). which is weird

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want FPdf to work properly, there cannot be any output at all beside what fpdf generates.  You can solve the problem deleting all new line characters found at the end of the .php files, using the following regular expression

> \?>\n\z

replaced with

> \?\n

For example:

```
<?php
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Ok, OK
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

But this won't work

```
<?php
echo "You don't sent  before output";
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'OK oK);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes @Fortran, but i found the problem. It is the "align" attributes in my table. I remove that, and it works ok now. pheww...